# FTP Client for PIC microcontroller

Tags: c, pic, microchip

Does anyone know of a Source Code for a FTP Client that I can use with a PIC microcontroller?
Preferably in C and I am using a PIC 18F97J60. It is ok even if the source is for a different PIC, I can modify it to support my need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2505&param=en535724) page:

Microchip offers a free licensed TCP/IP stack optimized for the PIC18, PIC24, dsPIC and PIC32 microcontroller families. As shown in figure below, the stack is divided into multiple layers, where each layer accesses services from one or more layers directly below it. Per specifications, many of the TCP/IP layers are “live”, in the sense that they not only act when a service is requested, but also when events like time-out or new packet arrival occurs. Microchip’s TCP/IP stack includes the following key features:

- Optimized for all PIC18, PIC24, dsPIC and PIC32 families
- Supported Protocols: ARP, IP, ICMP, UDP, TCP, DHCP, SNMP, HTTP, FTP, TFTP

EDIT: This package does not include source for an FTP client; only an FTP server.  So this can get you most of the way there.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's an accurate, helpful response.

Comment: Well, I just downloaded and looked at the source code.  Among all it provides, it doesn't provide an FTP client, only a server.  Post edited.

Answer (score -2):

There are so many open source code, such as(get from google):
http://www.thefreecountry.com/webmaster/freeftpclients.shtml

Comment: C'mon did you even read the question!